# server is getting wreird IP address from client

Tags: ip, local, public

I have a static local IP Address: 10.8.4.*, and the public IP Address of my machine is: 72.43.135.*. when the server(sitting on different network from my workstation) gets a request from my machine, it sees my IP address from

Context.Request.UserHostAddress

and got 10.20.102.*.

why it the server not getting the IP as: 72.43.135.*?

Comment: and what is 10.20.102.* here?

Answer (score 0):

If you define *public* and *local*, you will get to know that these terms might refere to the same network under some conditions. This could be a demilitarized zone (DMZ) for example.

What IP the destination server sees, depends on the interface you send the packets through and the routers it crosses.

**Is there masquerading (NAT) ?** - Is the main question. You can be on totally different networks but the routers might still forward your local IP, now this also depends on the routing table. Can a packet find its way back to your host? Is there a reversed route from the host to your machine?

The destination host is propably having 2 interfaces, 1 with IP 72.43.. one with a 10.8.. maybe it recieves through the 72 but sends back through the 10.8 because it has a different route back. Networking can be real voodoo! Trace your packets, ask your sysadmins..

(not talking about proxies here, they deliver different custom headers with different IPs)